# Undefined reference to `fftwav_mu_', 'fftext_mu_' when compiling Vasp

Tags: makefile, fortran, fftw, intel-fortran, intel-mkl

I am trying to compile vasp 6.2.1 in my ubuntu 19.10 on VirtualBox. I have intel openApi (which has ifortran compiler) and fftw3 installed. I am trying to compile the serial version using ifort. But it's giving me an error as follows.

> 

```
if [ ! -d build ] ; then mkdir build  ; fi
if [ ! -d build/std ] ; then mkdir build/std  ; fi
cp src/makefile src/.objects src/makedeps.awk makefile.include build/std 
make -C build/std VERSION=std cleandependencies -j1
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/mdazharul/vasp/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp.6.2.1/build/std'
rm -f .depend
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mdazharul/vasp/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp.6.2.1/build/std'
make -C build/std VERSION=std all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/mdazharul/vasp/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp.6.2.1/build/std'
rsync -ru ../../src/lib .
cp makefile.include lib
make -C lib -j1
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/mdazharul/vasp/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp.6.2.1/build/std/lib'
make libdmy.a
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/mdazharul/vasp/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp.6.2.1/build/std/lib'
make[3]: 'libdmy.a' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mdazharul/vasp/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp.6.2.1/build/std/lib'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mdazharul/vasp/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp.6.2.1/build/std/lib'
rsync -ru ../../src/parser .
cp makefile.include parser
make -C parser -j1
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/mdazharul/vasp/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp.6.2.1/build/std/parser'
make libparser.a
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/mdazharul/vasp/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp.6.2.1/build/std/parser'
make[3]: 'libparser.a' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mdazharul/vasp/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp.6.2.1/build/std/parser'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mdazharul/vasp/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp.6.2.1/build/std/parser'
rsync -u ../../src/*.F ../../src/*.inc .
rm -f vasp ; make vasp ; cp vasp ../../bin/vasp_std
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/mdazharul/vasp/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp.6.2.1/build/std'
mpiifort -qmkl=cluster -lstdc++ -o vasp c2f_interface.o nccl2for.o simd.o base.o profiling.o string.o tutor.o version.o vhdf5_base.o incar_reader.o reader_base.o openmp.o openacc_struct.o mpi.o mpi_shmem.o mathtools.o hamil_struct.o radial_struct.o pseudo_struct.o mgrid_struct.o wave_struct.o nl_struct.o mkpoints_struct.o poscar_struct.o afqmc_struct.o phonon_struct.o fock_glb.o chi_glb.o smart_allocate.o xml.o extpot_glb.o constant.o vdwforcefield_glb.o jacobi.o main_mpi.o openacc.o scala.o asa.o lattice.o poscar.o ini.o mgrid.o setex_struct.o xclib.o vdw_nl.o xclib_grad.o setex.o radial.o pseudo.o gridq.o ebs.o symlib.o mkpoints.o random.o wave.o wave_mpi.o wave_high.o bext.o spinsym.o symmetry.o lattlib.o nonl.o nonlr.o nonl_high.o dfast.o choleski2.o mix.o hamil.o xcgrad.o xcspin.o potex1.o potex2.o constrmag.o cl_shift.o relativistic.o LDApU.o paw_base.o metagga.o egrad.o pawsym.o pawfock.o pawlhf.o diis.o rhfatm.o hyperfine.o fock_ace.o paw.o mkpoints_full.o charge.o Lebedev-Laikov.o stockholder.o dipol.o solvation.o scpc.o pot.o tet.o dos.o elf.o hamil_rot.o chain.o dyna.o fileio.o vhdf5.o sphpro.o us.o core_rel.o aedens.o wavpre.o wavpre_noio.o broyden.o dynbr.o reader.o writer.o xml_writer.o brent.o stufak.o opergrid.o stepver.o chgloc.o fast_aug.o fock_multipole.o fock.o fock_dbl.o fock_frc.o mkpoints_change.o subrot_cluster.o sym_grad.o mymath.o npt_dynamics.o subdftd3.o subdftd4.o internals.o dynconstr.o dimer_heyden.o dvvtrajectory.o vdwforcefield.o nmr.o pead.o k-proj.o subrot.o subrot_scf.o paircorrection.o rpa_force.o ml_interface.o force.o pwlhf.o gw_model.o optreal.o steep.o rmm-diis.o davidson.o david_inner.o root_find.o lcao_bare.o locproj.o electron_common.o electron.o rot.o electron_all.o shm.o pardens.o optics.o constr_cell_relax.o stm.o finite_diff.o elpol.o hamil_lr.o rmm-diis_lr.o subrot_lr.o lr_helper.o hamil_lrf.o elinear_response.o ilinear_response.o linear_optics.o setlocalpp.o wannier.o electron_OEP.o electron_lhf.o twoelectron4o.o gauss_quad.o m_unirnk.o minimax_ini.o minimax_dependence.o minimax_functions1D.o minimax_functions2D.o minimax_struct.o minimax_varpro.o minimax.o mlwf.o ratpol.o pade_fit.o screened_2e.o wave_cacher.o crpa.o chi_base.o wpot.o local_field.o ump2.o ump2kpar.o fcidump.o ump2no.o bse_te.o bse.o time_propagation.o acfdt.o afqmc.o rpax.o chi.o acfdt_GG.o dmft.o GG_base.o greens_orbital.o lt_mp2.o rnd_orb_mp2.o greens_real_space.o chi_GG.o chi_super.o sydmat.o rmm-diis_mlr.o linear_response_NMR.o wannier_interpol.o wave_interpolate.o linear_response.o auger.o dmatrix.o phonon.o wannier_mats.o elphon.o core_con_mat.o embed.o extpot.o fft3dfurth.o fft3dlib.o main.o  -Llib -ldmy -Lparser -lparser -Lparser -lparser -lstdc++ 
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved fftext_mu_
        Referenced in /tmp/ipo_ifortQlEAwA.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved fftext_useinv_mu_
        Referenced in /tmp/ipo_ifortQlEAwA.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved fftwav_mu_
        Referenced in /tmp/ipo_ifortQlEAwA.o
ipo: warning #11021: unresolved fftwav_useinv_mu_
        Referenced in /tmp/ipo_ifortQlEAwA.o
ld: /tmp/ipo_ifortQlEAwA2.o: in function `wave_high_mp_fftext_wa_':
ipo_out2.f:(.text.hot00012+0x2d442): undefined reference to `fftext_useinv_mu_'
ld: ipo_out2.f:(.text.hot00012+0x2d597): undefined reference to `fftext_mu_'
ld: /tmp/ipo_ifortQlEAwA2.o: in function `wave_high_mp_fftwav_wa_':
ipo_out2.f:(.text.hot00012+0x2d865): undefined reference to `fftwav_useinv_mu_'
ld: ipo_out2.f:(.text.hot00012+0x2d99f): undefined reference to `fftwav_mu_'
make[2]: *** [makefile:149: vasp] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mdazharul/vasp/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp.6.2.1/build/std'
cp: cannot stat 'vasp': No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [makefile:146: all] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mdazharul/vasp/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp6.2.1/vasp.6.2.1/build/std'
make: *** [makefile:17: std] Error 2
```

I am Also including the makefile.include.

```
>

# Precompiler options
CPP_OPTIONS= -DHOST=\"LinuxIFC\"\
             -DCACHE_SIZE=16000 \
             -Davoidalloc \
             -Duse_bse_te \
             -Dtbdyn \
             -Dfock_dblbuf

CPP        = fpp -f_com=no -free -w0  $*$(FUFFIX) $*$(SUFFIX) $(CPP_OPTIONS)

FC         = mpiifort
FCL        = mpiifort -qmkl=cluster -lstdc++

FREE       = -free -names lowercase

FFLAGS     = -assume byterecl -w -xHOST
OFLAG      = -O2
OFLAG_IN   = $(OFLAG)
DEBUG      = -O0

MKL_PATH   = $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64
BLAS       =
LAPACK     =
BLACS      =
SCALAPACK  =

OBJECTS    = fft3dfurth.o fft3dlib.o

INCS       =-I$(MKLROOT)/include/fftw

LLIBS      = $(SCALAPACK) $(LAPACK) $(BLAS)

OBJECTS_O1 += fft3dfurth.o fftw3d.o fftmpi.o fftmpiw.o
OBJECTS_O2 += fft3dlib.o

# For what used to be vasp.5.lib
CPP_LIB    = $(CPP)
FC_LIB     = $(FC)
CC_LIB     = icc
CFLAGS_LIB = -O
FFLAGS_LIB = -O1
FREE_LIB   = $(FREE)

OBJECTS_LIB= linpack_double.o

# For the parser library
CXX_PARS   = icpc
LLIBS      += -Lparser -lparser -lstdc++

# Normally no need to change this
SRCDIR     = ../../src
BINDIR     = ../../bin
```

I can not seem to locate the problem. Please help me regarding this matter. Thank you.

`

Comment: Did you create the makefile or was it supplied to you? Did you change something there?

Comment: It was supplied to me and I read through it. I didn't find anything that needs editing.

Comment: Did you install full MKL with OneAPI as well? Please show more of the output. The command that was called by `make` and caused the error is necessary.

Comment: Yes, sir, I have installed the latest mkl library that comes with OpenAPI. I have included the full command line output now. Please let me know what I need to do. Thank you.

Comment: You are also missing the MPI library.

Comment: But I am trying to compile serial version, do I need MPI library for that? Is that the only issue?

Comment: It looks like you're using a version of the MKL library which requires MPI. You either need to install and link against MPI, or It may be possible to compile MKL so that it doesn't need MPI, but that's not what you have right now.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to Linux. In order to link the mkl library, I am using intel oneAPI mkl link line advisor. It gave me a link line and compiler options. Could you please tell me what to do with this link line? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have not compiled the fftwxf3xf library yet. Intel ONEAPI needs you to compile it manually.

```
cd /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/latest/interfaces/fftw3xf
sudo make libintel64
```

Then recompile VASP code. It should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try compiling your application using mpiifort instead of doing it with ifort compiler. You are getting the *undefined reference to `MPI_Comm_rank* errors because your application did not get linked with the MPI libraries. mpiifort compiler uses intel ifort compiler along with MPI wrappers.

Comment: I have compiled it with mpiifort and the error is no more. but now I have a different error. Could you please check the edited codes to check the error? What is that for? I have fftw 3.3.10 installed and environment variables set. Thank you.